# Jackson ObjectMapper() constructor throws NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, json, jackson, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using Jackson sample code to deserialize a POJO:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
```

This line throws a NoSuchMethodError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBase.<init>(TypeBase.java:15)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType.<init>(SimpleType.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType.<init>(SimpleType.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeBindings.<clinit>(TypeBindings.java:18)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._fromType(TypeFactory.java:525)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:179)
    at com.me.util.ctrl.BillingJobStatus.fromJson(BillingJobStatus.java:37)
```

I don't get it

Comment: The exclusion mechanism worked when facing this error with hadoop. I also had to exclude jackson-core-asl from the hadoop core dependency.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm guessing your Jackson JARs are out of sync. The `JavaType` class is in the `jackson-core` JAR, and the `ObjectMapper` class is in `jackson-mapper`.

Make sure these are both of the same version.

Comment: Yes, this is an unfortunate but common pitfall, which can easily occur, especially when using Maven.

Comment: @StaxMan agreed, it's a common pitfall but, without a doubt, Maven helps by explicitly declaring dependency versions.

Comment: @SeanConnolly true, I should probably have clarified; it's rather a generic issue with transitive dependencies, not really with Maven but modelling.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be as easy as this.  There is only one version of jackson-mapper in maven.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.  The core jar was 1.7.1 while the mapper was 1.8.1.  Note: To fix this for maven I added an exclusion and pulled down the proper version.

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick here is to exclude jackson from the dependencies that use it.

To check which dependencies import it, you can use the following maven command:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.codehaus.jackson`

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was due to yammer-metrics library including an older version of jackson.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the amazonaws sdk that caused this. Using just the exclusion for jackson-mapper-asl didn't work but using an exclusion for core and mapper did:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

While working on Hadoop, I eliminated this error by setting the following exclusions

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>   
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is beacuse of @RequestBody use different jars for different spring versions : 
if using spring 4 than have to add different jars :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

if using spring 3 have to use this jar :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Until I started using annotation @RequestBody (Spring v4.0.6) everything worked fine with jackson-all-1.9.6.jar. Using jackson-all-1.9.6.jar and Spring v3.x works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anyone who is facing this issue, he should definetely investigate the dependencies with

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.codehaus.jackson
```

In my case, I had a jackson dependency on Atmosphere-Socket-io :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-socketio</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

It took me several hours to track that down, thank you all guys for the above solutions which inspired me! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem when migrating my WebApp from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 8.
On Tomcat6 and Tomcat7 my WebApp would start just fine, but on Tomcat8 I would get this exception(seems that T6 and T7 loads classes alphabeticaly but T8 doesn't - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26642798/1864614).

The problem was that I was having 2 versions of the class

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
```

As answered by @wild_nothing I have checked dependency the tree to list all dependencies on *org.codehaus.jackson*

In my case the problem was that I had several versions of libraries that provided this class:

- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:jar:1.5.0
- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:jar:1.5.0
- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.2
- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.2

My solution was to exclude the older versions(1.5.0) and only leave the 1.8.2 version

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>cfm.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jive</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

- in this case *jive* was depending on older 1.5.0 version