# Hibernate - Error activating Bean Validation integration

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to set up Hibernate. But when i try to create my Session Factory, with this code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:217)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:445)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:150)
        ... 31 more
```

I have the hibernate-validator and the bean validator in my class-path (see screenshot) [image]

What could be the issues here?

**Edit** I had two additional validation-api on the classpath, but excluded them. Could they be a problem somehow. Maybe the scope=provided?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
    <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Edit 2**

Solved the problem: I had yet another bean validator jar in the class path. But not from maven, so i didn't realize it. Removing that solved the problem. Thanks a lot for the hints!

Comment: By the `NoSuchMethodError`, I would investigate issues with the versions of libraries/jvm (that you are using a library so old that it does not provide the expected method).

Comment: ... tough the versions shown in the classpath should match (1.1.0 is the last release library)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a BeanValidation 1.0 API version on the classpath as well. In Bvean Validation 1.0 there is no _ParameterNameProvider_, so that would explain the error.

Comment: I had two additional validation-api on my classpath, but excluded them -> see my edit. Could that be the problem?

Comment: This question may help anyone else who encounters this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656146/unable-to-run-hibernate-validator#21656166

Answer (score 4):

`NoSuchMethodError` indicates that you have loaded wrong version of jar that has no method named like which you have used.
I highly recommend you to use hibernate 4.0 or little lower which turn out to be more stable to transplant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from having similar packaged structure jar.
In my case, I had `javaee6` as provided, and `javax.validation1.1.0.Final` both have the package `javax.validation.spi`.

Since I used Maven, I placed javax.validation1.1.0 dependency on top of javaee6. So I can use 1.1.0 methods. Otherwise, if the javaee6 is on top I cannot access/ override validation1.1.0 methods.

It compiled fine, but while running in `Tomee 1.7.5` WebProfile I faced `NoSuchMethodError`. So, added the javax.validation1.1.0 Final jar to lib folder of Tomee, but still somehow javaee6 jar's validation got triggered first.

So I renamed the file `javax.validation1.1.0.Final` to `ijavax.validation1.1.0.Final`, so that when alphabetically ordered it gets loaded before javaee6, then it worked!!

Check here for class loader ordering of jars in tomcat [Order of loading jar files from lib directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474765/order-of-loading-jar-files-from-lib-directory)

Comment: This is a terrible hack that relies on internal ordering constraints that could change at any time.