# LifecycleException with Hibernate, Maven and TomEE server

Tags: hibernate, maven, jsf, apache-tomee, lifecycleexception

I'm a newbie in JSF,

I created a new Dynamic Web Project, converted it into a Maven project, then I added the TomEE server (I tried to start the server and it worked).

I followed this tutorial which explains how to Intall Hibernate on a TomEE server : http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-hibernate.html, I did not installed Ehcache and Infinispan.

Now when I try to launch the server I get many exceptions, here's a part of it  :

```
INFOS: Undeploying app: C:\Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT
juin 01, 2016 11:14:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
GRAVE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1038)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1537)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1518)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:762)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1982)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:839)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

juin 01, 2016 11:14:30 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFOS: Undeployed app: C:\Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT
juin 01, 2016 11:14:30 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:843)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:35)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.doPrivBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:131)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:129)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.run(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:47)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.bindValidators(Assembler.java:891)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:785)
    ... 14 more

juin 01, 2016 11:14:30 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFOS: ------------------------- localhost -> /jreservation
juin 01, 2016 11:14:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1270)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ROOT: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:843)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:35)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.doPrivBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:131)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:129)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.run(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:47)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.bindValidators(Assembler.java:891)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:785)
    ... 14 more
```

My dependencies :

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My Web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jreservation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

In `Properties -> Project Facets` :

- Dynamic Web Module is at 3.0
- Java at 1.6,
- JSF at 2.2,
- JAX-RS at 1.1,
- JPA at 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have an older version of validation-api on somewhere your classpath. Try to use the dependency hierarchy to understand if you have some old dependencies in the reactor...

Try also adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

If it still does not work, consider using hibernate-validator.

See these links too:

[Hibernate - Error activating Bean Validation integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266297/hibernate-error-activating-bean-validation-integration)

[Trouble starting Hibernate Validator due to Bean Validation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656146/trouble-starting-hibernate-validator-due-to-bean-validation-api)

When you have dependencies missing or conflicts the best and first thing to do is see dependencies inherited into the reactor, some time just adding something or excluding something avoid you to have a lot of pain!

Last thing, seeing on the web similar issue with same hibernate versions, i find the below answers pretty useful:

> On the Hibernate Validator site, for 5.0.3.Final it says: This
>   transitively pulls in the dependency to the Bean Validation API
>   (javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final). But it seems to have
>   issues inheriting this..
>
> I was able to make this work with 5.0.3.Final. By adding a dependency
>   to javax.validation:validation-api 1.1.0.Final , and **making sure this
>   dependency is placed before the hibernate-validatory dependency**, it
>   not works fine.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks! Validator was indeed the problem.

Comment: Happy for this... please if it helps you, vote it :)

Comment: Whoops sorry I forgot it

Comment: No Problem! Thanks, i appreciate it :)