# how tomcat will load the class if duplicate classes exist with same package structure

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, classloader, tomcat8

Jboss-allclient.jar and jboss-logging.jar have a class **org.jboss.logging.Logger** , where the methods defined inside the classes are different but the package structure is same for both the classes. Due to which i have got an exception on deployment.

**Exception**

NoSuchMethodException of getMessage()

This is because, getMessage() method is present in one class alone. Unfortunately, it picks the wrong class and throws an exception.

Note :

This is working in tomcat 7 (windows and linux version) and tomcat8 (Windows)
**Not** working in tomcat 8 (**Linux version**).
JRE version is 8

Those two jars needed for my application.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474765/order-of-loading-jar-files-from-lib-directory

Comment: @PankajPandey. i went through the given link, Didnt get the answer for my question. my question is , what do i need to get rid off this problem? i have both jars under WEB-INF/lib/ and the mentioned class exists in both jars. but the definition of the classes is different. Thats is why i am getting this exception only in tomcat 8 (Linux version). Not with tomcat 7 (windows and linux) and tomcat 8 (Windows version).

Comment: That link described the order of class loading , before tomcat 8 the order was alphabetic but in tomcat 8 the order is random and dependent on underlying os. The workaround is if you move your one of your low order jar file into tomcat/lib, then it may work.please try.

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat 8 the sequence of loading jars within a single war is not guaranteed. Before it was alphabetical.

It was reported as a bug to Apache, but they claim it's a feature ;) Check https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57129

One of the devs has come up with a workaround, but I have not tried it. You can have a look on https://github.com/openwide-java/tomcat-classloader-ordered

Good luck!