# Unable to start Spring Boot 1.5.1 application on Standalone Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat8

I'm ported my application to `Spring Boot 1.5.1` and unable to start it with a `Standalone Tomcat 8.5.2` with a following error:

```
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:api' did not find a matching property.
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.2
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
   log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
     feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource

    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-crypto-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-jwt-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-config-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-core-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-facebook-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-github-1.0.0.M4.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-google-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-linkedin-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-security-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-web-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-core-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-schema-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spi-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-common-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger2-2.6.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/swagger-models-1.5.10.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
    WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1405)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1395)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5e39fc3c]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4980)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@53d8bd75]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
        ... 13 more

    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1405)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1395)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 6 more

    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 11 more

    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:352)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:645)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1072)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    feb 03, 2017 2:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:352)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:645)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1072)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

This is my `lib` folder in a war file:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-5.0.3.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar
caffeine-2.3.5.jar
cdi-api-2.0-EDR1.jar
classmate-1.3.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-compress-1.12.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-validator-1.5.0.jar
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
domain-0.0.1.jar
groovy-2.4.7.jar
gson-2.8.0.jar
guava-19.0-rc1.jar
hazelcast-all-3.7.2.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.6.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar
javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
logback-core-1.1.9.jar
lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar
lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.0.jar
lucene-codecs-5.5.0.jar
lucene-core-5.5.0.jar
lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar
mapstruct-1.0.0.Final.jar
metrics-core-3.1.2.jar
metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar
neo4j-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-backup-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-causal-clustering-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-cluster-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-codegen-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-collections-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-com-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-command-line-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-common-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-consistency-check-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-csv-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-cypher-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3-2.3.7.jar
neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.0-3.0.7.jar
neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3-2.3.7.jar
neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.0-3.0.7.jar
neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-dbms-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-enterprise-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-enterprise-kernel-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-graph-algo-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-graph-matching-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-graphdb-api-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-ha-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-import-tool-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-io-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-java-driver-1.1.0.jar
neo4j-jmx-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-kernel-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-logging-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-lucene-index-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-lucene-upgrade-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-management-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-metrics-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-ogm-compiler-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.1.1.jar
neo4j-primitive-collections-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-query-logging-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-resource-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-udc-3.1.0.jar
neo4j-unsafe-3.1.0.jar
netty-3.9.9.Final.jar
netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar
ognl-3.0.8.jar
opencsv-2.3.jar
parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar
parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.7.jar
scala-library-2.11.8.jar
scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-actuator-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-security-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-social-facebook-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-social-twitter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-validation-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-neo4j-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-jwt-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-config-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-core-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-facebook-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-github-1.0.0.M4.jar
spring-social-google-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-linkedin-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-security-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-twitter-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-web-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
springfox-core-2.6.0.jar
springfox-schema-2.6.0.jar
springfox-spi-2.6.0.jar
springfox-spring-web-2.6.0.jar
springfox-swagger-common-2.6.0.jar
springfox-swagger-ui-2.6.0.jar
springfox-swagger2-2.6.0.jar
swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar
swagger-models-1.5.10.jar
thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar
thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

This is `lib-provided` :

```
javaee-web-api-7.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar
```

Embedded Tomcat starts perfectly but Standalone fail.

What can be wrong with my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log file has error `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)` which means one of the jar file is corrupted. You can try to cleanup local maven repository and rebuild/repackage the application.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it was the issue

Answer (score 0):

**May be class mixup of different versions and precedence of jar could be the reason.**

Embedded Tomcat version: **8.5.11**
Standalone Tomcat version: **8.5.2**

Try removing the embedded tomcat jars from the project while running  in a standalone container.

[Order of loading jar files from lib directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474765/order-of-loading-jar-files-from-lib-directory)