# Duplicate classes in a web application

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a maven Spring Boot web application with quite a few (transitive) dependencies.

There are `.jar` files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder inside  the built `.war`.

For example:

- `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`
- `javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar`

Both of these contain a class called `javax/persistence/JoinColumn.class` (with different file sizes).

At runtime, which "version" is going to be referenced when I use it in the code?
Can this type of dependency cause problems later?

Comment: Yes, they can cause problems (noclassdef, nosuchmethoderror, etc.). How do you avoid this? You locate dependencies supplying the same class and pick one, exclude the other.

Comment: @w9n7cxx5fM8 the first one Java finds on the classpath. It will cause problems that's for sure. You should be sure about dependencies versions you're using

Comment: The whole point of Spring Boot is that you don't have to worry about dependencies. Could you include your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I can't really exclude the other, because there are some classes which are **only** in one of the `.jar`s.

Comment: @w9n7cxx5fM8 If my answer was sufficient, would you mind marking it as Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. **You don't know**.
2. Yes, this will cause problems later.

For a more elaborate answer, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474838/7430994