# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.configure

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I am using the following code and which throws the exception

```
accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.configure(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator$Feature;Z)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;
```

The JavaType class is in the jackson-core JAR, and the ObjectMapper class is in jackson-mapper are both of the same version.

Comment: Double-check the versions of core vs mapper, and make sure you don't have more than one of each of those jars on the classpath. All evidence is they are out of sync. [Similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094180/jackson-objectmapper-constructor-throws-nosuchmethod).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated the jars to the latest version and it has solved the problem :)